# AJAX Drop Down without database

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am a newbie to ajax, i need to use a populating  dropdownlist. i.e when i select the particular particular item from drop down list. it should display an web page.how can i do this?

Comment: Ajax is generally to update existings webpage than displaying brand new page for a component action. It seems there is some ambiguity in your technology selection. You are not clear on what technologies you are using, if java (or) .Net, its better to use MVC feature to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery autocomple. I know this is not exactly drop-down, but in some cases it can work.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Answer (score 0):

That shouldn't even need ajax.  If you associate the dropdown selection to particular web page you can just open the page.  See [Javascript: open new page in same window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267704/javascript-open-new-page-in-same-window) for instructions on this.

Using a framework like jQuery (recommended) you could use the .change() event handler.  See:
http://api.jquery.com/change/