# Javascript - opening a link

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, href

My Javascript isnt up to scratch, and im having problems making the link open in the same window rather than a new popup.

In my html I have the following link

```
<a href="javascript:go_registerParamList('<%=appendStr%>');">Open An Account</a>
```

The Javascript for the 'go_registerParamList' is:

```
function go_registerParamList(paramList) {
    if (self.opener == null) {
        var base_window = self;
    } else {
        var base_window = self.opener;
    }
    if (paramList == '') {
        var link = 'https://${accountUrl}?action=go_register_popup&area=SK&button=openregbutton&promo=new_regbutton_en&crea=img&bus_channel=SK';
    } else {
        var link = 'https://${accountUrl}?action=go_register_popup&area=SK&button=openregbutton&promo=new_regbutton_en&crea=img' + '&' + paramList;
    }

    base_window.open(link, "pp_registration", "width=642, height=620, scrollbars=no,  menubar=no, status=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=yes,screenX=5, screenY=5, left=5, top=5");
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267704/javascript-open-new-page-in-same-window

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript function :

```
function openInSameWindow(evt) {
    window.location=evt;
}
```

HTML hyperlink to open in same window :

```
<a onclick="openInSameWindow('http://google.com')">Click to open in same window</a>
```

You can call the function `openInSameWindow` to open a link in same window.

Answer (score 1):

The `.open()` method opens a new window.

Instead, you can just do:

```
window.location = link;
```

So:

```
function go_registerParamList(paramList)
{
    var link;
    if(paramList == '')
    {
        link = 'https://${accountUrl}?action=go_register_popup&area=SK&button=openregbutton&promo=new_regbutton_en&crea=img&bus_channel=SK';
    }
    else
    {
        link = 'https://${accountUrl}?action=go_register_popup&area=SK&button=openregbutton&promo=new_regbutton_en&crea=img&' + paramList;
    }
    window.location = link; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use window.open(URL,name,specs,replace) name as "_self "

```
 window.open(link, "_self" , "width=642, height=620, scrollbars=no,  menubar=no, status=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=yes,screenX=5, screenY=5, left=5, top=5");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load a new document into the current window with `window.location.assign(link)`.

See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
Before you call the base_window.open() method try to alert the link variable. If its 
okay then you may not have problem with that.

Thanks.
```