# How to open a new tab in the same window

Tags: javascript, window

I'm trying to open a new page in a new tab.

I've tried `window.open ('MyURL');` without informing a name but still it opens in a new window.

I can't replace the current tab, I need to open a new tab with a new content.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're saying you want to open the new URL in a new tab, right?

Refer to these questions, which were in the related search:
[Javascript: open new page in same window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267704/javascript-open-new-page-in-same-window)
[Open a URL in a new tab (and not a new window) using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-url-in-new-tab-using-javascript)

Specifically,
`window.open(url, '_blank');`

The _blank should do it, if I understand what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry for the incorrect title, would be best "opening a new tab in the same window"

When I use the onclick event directly

<img class="btnImprimir" id="btnImprimir1" src="/Images//btnImprimir.png" onclick="window.open('DespxFat.aspx)"/>

The browser opens a new tab

But if I use window.open in a function

<img class="btnImprimir" id="btnImprimir1" src="/Images//btnImprimir.png" onclick="OpenReport()"/>

OpenReport function () {
    window.open ('DespxFat.aspx);
}

The browser opens a new window

Comment: So did the _blank help with that? I guess I've never see that behavior differ from place to place like that.

Answer (score 1):

Simply do

```
window.location = 'MyURL';
```

This will replace the current page in the same window.