# HTML basic button code for opening webpage in new window

Tags: javascript, html

Newbie question here. The following link works well to open a new window to a specified webpage.

```
<a onclick="window.open('','page','location=0,toolbar=0,...')"
href="mypage.html" target="page">My Link</a>
```

I need to replace the link with a button, but can't get it to work. Here's what I've got:

```
<button onclick="window.open('','page','location=0,toolbar=0,...')" 
href="mypage.html" target="page"
type="button">My Button</button>
```

It appears that `href` and `target` are not attributes of button. Looking for recommendations how to fix this for best browser compatibility.

Comment: Just put the URL to be opened as first parameter into the `window.open` call in the first place …? But this is kinda nonsense – functionality that refers to other pages _should_ be using links. If you want a link to _look_ like a button, then format it with CSS.

Comment: Why do you want to use `<button>`? You can use `<a>` and change styles.

Comment: The HTML "theme" I'm using states `it is a best practice and highly recommended to use the <button> element whenever possible to ensure matching cross-browser rendering. For example, there's a Firefox bug that prevents setting the line-height of <input>-based buttons, etc.` Other than that I've no idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why not try:

```
<a onclick="window.open('','page','location=0,toolbar=0,...')"
href="mypage.html" target="page"><button>My Link</button></a>
```

Comment: Any pros or cons versus just including the webpage link as the first parameter in the `window.open()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/233467/whats-the-best-way-to-open-new-browser-window

And I don't really see any pros or cons of specifying links in the first parameter. if you use a button, you can add the url as the first parameter of the window.open() function and ignore the target and href attributes unsupported by button!

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
<button onclick="window.open(yourwebsite+'/mypage.html')">My Button</button>
```

Comment: You forgot about the name of the window.